# How to display the error message after uploading the sheet also if it is not a correct document

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file-upload

Below is my javascript code which clears the label message not a vaild document while choosing the file using fileuploader but the problem is it works fine in hiding the label message till it is not uploaded successfully but once if the file is uploaded again if i upload the fle by giving wrong month and year i need to show not a valid document but it is not displaying anything

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  onchange="callme();" />

function callme() {
 document.getElementById("your message label id").value= "";
}

if (month == ddlmonth.SelectedValue && year == ddlyear.SelectedValue)
{
  Ismatch = true;
  //break;
}
else
{
  Ismatch = false;
  break;
}
}
if (Ismatch == true)
{
  lblerrorMessage.Visible = false;
  lblerrorMessage.Text = "Valid Document";
}
else
{
  lblerrorMessage.Text = "Not a Valid Document";
  ddlmonth.ClearSelection();
  ddlyear.ClearSelection();
  label1.Text = "";
  return;
}
```

Comment: You could use a response message and based on that you can trigger a message.

Comment: How can i do it already my c# code is used to return the error message if it is not a valid document

Comment: You can use http status code example `200 is OK` , `201 is created` etc.
for more details please check the below url.
[link](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml)

Comment: Already i have label messages in my c# code my problem is to display the label message even after uploading successfully if it is not a valid document

Comment: Please check the answer. i hope it should work based on the variables you have provided

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in the code and hope it should work based on the variables  you have provided in the code.

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  onchange="callme();" />

    function callme() {
     document.getElementById("your message label id").value= "";
     lblerrorMessage.Visible = true;

    if (month == ddlmonth.SelectedValue && year == ddlyear.SelectedValue)
    {
      lblerrorMessage.Text = "Valid Document";
    }
    else
    {
lblerrorMessage.Text = "Not a Valid Document";
      ddlmonth.ClearSelection();
      ddlyear.ClearSelection();
      label1.Text = "";

    }
}
```

Comment: that means should i remove it in my c# code in code behind

Comment: Yes make a backup and try the current one, just now also i made a change. make sure you are using the current snippet

Comment: Ok, please debug the code and check whether `callme()` method is triggering while uploading. If yes check the values of `ddlmonth.SelectedValue` and `ddlyear.SelectedValue`

Comment: they are undefined because i am handling completely in code behind

Comment: so is the file upload is also handling in code behind?

Comment: yes validations fileupload everything is handled in .cs

Comment: can you please use the example provided in the below link
http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/